# jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu attaching a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I'm trying to implement the jfeinsteins sliding menu, however I'm having a problem getting a fragment to attach. The issue is that the layout is shown on the screen twice. I assume that this is because I setMenu and then do the replace (adding it again).

Could anyone provide some pointers please.

```
public void configureSlidingMenu()
{

    // configure the SlidingMenu
    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.setBehindOffset(120);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.fragment_slideoutmenu);
    getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.slideOutMenu, new SlideOutMenu())
    .commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this in my application...
Created a class Util like this:

```
public class Util {
    public static void atachLeftMenu(final Activity pActivity){

        final SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(pActivity);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(pActivity, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.side_menu);
        ( (ListView)(menu.findViewById(R.id.side_menu_list)) ).setAdapter(new leftMenuAdapter(pActivity));
        ( (ListView)(menu.findViewById(R.id.side_menu_list)) ).setOnItemClickListener( new DrawerItemClickListener(pActivity));
        //Set menu options and values
    }
}
```

And in every Activity i just call the Util's "atachLeftMenu" method.

```
Util.atachLeftMenu(this);
```

If you want to do it within a fragment you'll still have to pass it the activity so you could do something like this:

```
Util.atachLeftMenu(getActivity());
```